# How can I return a function that depends on two functions?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following function:

```
private func getFunctionToPlot() -> ((Double) -> Double) {
    var function: (Double) -> Double = sin + cos
    return function

}
```

I would like to return a function that takes a double and returns a double, but this functions should be something as `sin + cos`. Both sin and cos independently take a double and return a double, but how can I return something as `sin($0) + cos($0)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not compiling"? It most certainly does compile.

Comment: @matt, not really because function is not initialized, I also would like to know how to initialized that

Comment: Well, my answer shows you one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little broad, but the line you claim doesn't compile *does* compile; there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. The only problem is that your code is incomplete. Here is a test example that *is* complete:

```
private func getFunctionToPlot() -> ((Double) -> Double) {
    var function: (Double) -> Double
    function = {_ in return 2.0}
    return function
}
```

**EDIT** As for your revised question, here's a test example of the sort of thing you now seem to be trying to do:

```
func sin(_ d:Double) -> Double {return 1}
func cos(_ d:Double) -> Double {return 1}
private func getFunctionToPlot() -> ((Double) -> Double) {
    let f1: (Double) -> Double = sin
    let f2: (Double) -> Double = cos
    return {f1(f2($0))} // or maybe f1($0) + f2($0)
}
```

Comment: this is helpful, I have an idea of how to figure it out

Comment: Right, the idea is in your loop you might fetch the value to be assigned to `function` from somewhere else. Just make sure you _do_ give it a value, as the compiler won't pass on it unless you do.

Comment: thank you so much. I have changed a little bit my question because was very vague

Comment: It's still pretty vague. :) I have no idea what you mean by "a combination of two functions". You can't say stuff like `sin + cos` in Swift (and I can't imagine what that would mean in _any_ language).

Comment: I added an example of the sort of thing I imagine you might mean.

Comment: the last edit definitely solves my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Added another edit since now I think I see what you mean by `+` in your question.

Comment: btw in the end with sin and cos I was referring to the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Sure, my example is just to show the structure of the syntax you will need.

Comment: The first part of this answer is a wonderfully explicit and simple example of how to think about creation and packaging of a closure, but I'm stuck at what it's doing. Is it simply returning the value `2.0`?

Comment: @Confused Yes, it's just a syntactical example. My example functions do not _use_ their input. :) I was just showing the OP how to use functions as values and get this thing to compile.

Comment: Cheers. Thank you for this. This is the first time I really grok how to exploit closures in variables. Or something like that. Back to my DunningKruger world of naivety as bliss!

Comment: @Confused Modesty prevents me (okay no it doesn't) from recommending that you read my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_as_value

Comment: Which is my way of saying that this line is a gem: "If you’ve never used a programming language where functions are first-class citizens, perhaps you’d better sit down now, because what I’m about to tell you might make you feel a little faint:" and that what follows is right... I'm asking myself why I don't find the time to read more of your wisdom. Over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign a closure to function and it will work.
Current in your code snippet the function has value "nil" and since the return type is not "optional"(i.e., ((Double) -> Double)?) therefore the return type mismatches.

One possible way is either assign function a value:

```
private func getFunctionToPlot() -> ((Double) -> Double) {
    var function: (Double) -> Double
    function = { input in
        return input * 2
    }
    for element in brain.program {
        // do something
    }
    return function
}
```

Another approach will be make return type optional

```
private func getFunctionToPlot() -> ((Double) -> Double)? {
    var function: ((Double) -> Double)?
    for element in brain.program {
        // do something
    }
    return function
}
```